# Can't apply options of datalabels chartjs plugin in Vue

Tags: vue.js, plugins, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I tried to use `Chart.js` in **Vue** through `vue-chartjs`. Also, I used `[chartjs-plugin-datalabels][1]`. Currently, I can toggle a chart by clicking the "Show a chart" button.

[image: Current Status]

I could see values for each label in the chart. But, I couldn't customize the data labels.

[StackOverflow]

- [How to properly use the chartjs datalabels plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49392731/how-to-properly-use-the-chartjs-datalabels-plugin)
- [ChartJS: datalabels: show percentage value in Pie piece](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52044013/chartjs-datalabels-show-percentage-value-in-pie-piece)
- [Show values on top of bars in chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42556835/show-values-on-top-of-bars-in-chart-js)

[The plugin's Github Page]

- https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/issues/10
- https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/410

[JS Fiddle]

- https://jsfiddle.net/simonbrunel/mo5y35yg/
- https://jsfiddle.net/simonbrunel/0jhffwfd/

Even after reading information above, I couldn't make mine work.

I would greatly appreciate any advice of solving this problem. Thanks! :)

Some of my code is the following:

```
<script>
import PieChart from "./pieChart.js";
import ChartJSPluginDatalabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    PieChart
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isHidden: false,
      chartData: {
        labels: ["Green", "Red", "Blue"],
        datasets: [
          {
            backgroundColor: ["#41B883", "#E46651", "#00D8FF"],
            data: [1, 10, 5]
          }
        ]
      },
      options:{
        plugins: {
          datalabels: {
            color: 'white',
            textAlign: 'center',
            font: {
              weight: "bold",
              size: 16
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

> Please check out the entire code here :
>   https://codesandbox.io/embed/xy4x07q0o.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind options to `pie-chart`

```
  <pie-chart v-if="isHidden" :data="chartData" :options="options"></pie-chart>
```

Checkout demo here https://codesandbox.io/s/5kvll0xqyl